# Google Places API can't find places by name

Tags: google-places-api

I have an application that uses the places API to help find places near destinations (like London).  I prefer using nearby because it allows me to focus on one area, and it's also cheaper compared to text searches.

Unfortunately, I get answers that don't make a lot of sense.  As an example, if I search for:

```
name=London Eye
```

I get zero results (with or without quotes around it).

But if I search by keyword:

```
keyword=ferris wheel
```

London Eye is returned. Here are the relevant queries:

- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=[API_KEY]&sensor=false&location=51.52864165,-0.10179430&radius=47022&name=%22london%20eye%22
- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=[API_KEY]&sensor=false&location=51.52864165,-0.10179430&radius=47022&keyword=ferris%20wheel

Is there some rhyme or reason to this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, issue is that you are using the wrong parameter.

Check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) and you'll see that parameter you should be using is `keyword` instead of `name`

It will be then:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=[API_KEY]&sensor=false&location=51.52864165,-0.10179430&radius=47022&keyword=%22london%20eye%22
```

And that's working for me!

EDIT:

As I said, if you try:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=[API_KEY]&sensor=false&location=51.52864165,-0.10179430&radius=47022&keyword=%22london%20eye%22&name=%22london%20eye%22
```

You get as return a lot of results better than using those parameters alone.

**UPDATE**

As of 2018 the `name` parameter was deprecated in favor of the `keyword` parameter, so from now on it is recommended to use only `keyword` parameter in your requests.

The documentation currently reads

> **name** — A term to be matched against all content that Google has indexed for this place. **Equivalent to keyword.** The name field is no longer restricted to place names. Values in this field are combined with values in the keyword field and passed as part of the same search string. We recommend using only the keyword parameter for all search terms.

source: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The doc here:https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search says that keyword and name are both optional parameters.  In any case, I'll try it your way!

Comment: You're right, difference is that `name` compares your input against names of places in a more strict way. But you know, I just checked both of them with same info, and it returns a lot of results, all of them including `name` input in results. I'm editting answer now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Users can only use these **types** for response in google API: - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/supported_types

If You find a nearby restaurant then use this URL:

> `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=30.67995,76.72211&radius=15000&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Please use your key for a response.

[image: Postman Response with Image]

Comment: I've removed the API key from the post for security and privacy concerns. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey